# sendRawTransaction error in web3.js

Tags: web3js, sendrawtransaction

i am trying to send a request for my contract function to web3:

my code snippets is here:

```
const W3 = require('web3');
const express = require('express');
const ethTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;

let web3, contractAddress, contractABI, contract, fromAdd, myData, estGasPrice;

function connectContract(){
    const provider = new W3.providers.HttpProvider(`${process.env.INFURA_ROPSTEN_ADDRESS}${process.env.INFURA_ROPSTEN_KEY}`);
    web3 = new W3(provider);
    contractAddress = process.env.LBT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
    contractABI =JSON.parse(process.env.LBT_CONTRACT_ABI);
    contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
    console.log(web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(process.env.TEST_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY).address);
    fromAdd = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(process.env.TEST_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY).address;
}

const router = express.Router();
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) =>{
try{
await connectContract();

myData = contract.methods.freezeAccount(req.query.target).encodeABI();

web3.eth.estimateGas({
    to: contractAddress, 
    data: myData
 }).then(function(e_gas){
    estGasPrice =e_gas;
 });

const rawTx = {
    nonce: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAdd)+1,
    gasPrice: estGasPrice,
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(2100000),
    to: contractAddress,
    data: myData
  }
const tx = new ethTx(rawTx);
tx.sign(new Buffer(process.env.TEST_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY,'hex'));  

const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');
web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(raw, function(hash) {
res.send(hash);
});

}catch(err){
    next(err);
}});
module.exports = router;
```

but I got an error :

```
Error: Cannot convert string to buffer. toBuffer only supports 0x-prefixed hex strings and this string was given: [object Promise]1
    at Object.exports.toBuffer
```

how I send the raw transaction?

thank you.

Comment: Does your `TEST_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY` start with `0x`?

Comment: yes the private key start with 0x @goodvibration

Comment: What version of web3.js are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

```
Cannot convert string to buffer.
toBuffer only supports 0x-prefixed hex strings and this string was given:
[object Promise]1
```

Tells you that you have somewhere passed a `Promise` object without resolving it first.

Looking into your code, here is the unresolved promise:

```
nonce: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAdd)+1,
```

You must resolve the `Promise` object returned by `web3.eth.getTransactionCount`.

Here is one way to do it:

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAdd).then(function(nonce) {
    const rawTx = {
        nonce: Number(nonce)+1,
        gasPrice: estGasPrice,
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(2100000),
        to: contractAddress,
        data: myData
    }
    const tx = new ethTx(rawTx);
    tx.sign(new Buffer(process.env.TEST_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY,'hex'));
    const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
    const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');
    web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(raw, function(hash) {
        res.send(hash);
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion but i got this error : RangeError: private key length is invalid

Comment: @YaseminCırt: NO! That's a different problem in a different line in your code! Please accept this answer if it has solved the problem described in your question, and then post the new problem in a new question.